# Hosting legacy ASP.NET (not ASP.NET Core) in ServiceFabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

I am looking for the options to host existing ASP.NET Framework (**not** .NET Core, and **not** ASP.NET Core) applications in ServiceFabric hosted on-premise.

We host such legacy applications in IIS, as is the common practice I believe, and we are considering migrating them to an on-prem ServiceFabric cluster without (or at least, as little as possible) modifications.

I see that Visual Studio 2017 SF project templates do not have the "old ASP.NET", which makes me think that using old ASP.NET isn't preferred, if supported at all. I can understand that.

I understand that it is possible to deploy the application in a container with IIS, e.g. [with Windows IIS](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore-iis).

Are there other possibilities?

Comment: What app are we talking about, MVC (5), web api? WebForms?

Comment: We are talking the "old-style" WebAPIs and apps (pre-ASP.NET MVC Core), so, yes, 5.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing self-hosted ASP.Net WebAPI on Service Fabric for three years already. They did remove the .NET Framework WebAPI template when you create a Service Fabric App, but yes, you can still run a Self-hosted .Net Framework API on Service Fabric.

I still have my old code before so I pretty much do same thing over and over. This [tutorial](https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-webapi.md) would help a lot. it's the basics of doing a self-hosted WebAPI, hosting it on HTTPS is another thing after that.